# Bug no eclipse, como arrumar?

Tags: eclipse

Sempre que eu abro o eclipse, a maioria dos meus projetos ficam com erro... Erro em algo que não tem relação com nada...
Para eu arrumar o erro, é só editar alguma coisa no projeto e salvar. Pronto! Erro arrumado! Mas toda vez que eu inicio o eclipse é a mesma coisa.. Por exemplo, eu tiro uma chave, salvo, depois coloco dnv e já salvo. Tira o erro.. Mas como eu disse... Toda vez que eu abro o eclipse da isto.
Alguém sabe como arrumar?
Obrigado :D

OBS: Todos meu projetos são em JAVA. Esqueci de avisar... Tenho em média de uns 20 projetos. Mas a maioria é projeto pequeno.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em qual linguagem acontence? são muitos projetos abertos?

Comment: Todos meu projetos são em JAVA. Esqueci de avisar... Tenho em média de uns 20 projetos. Mas a maioria é projeto pequeno.

Comment: Coloque uma imagem desses erros, isso ai pode ter varias causas.... quando o eclipse é aberto acontecem várias validações/verificações no código fonte das várias linguaguens do projeto, java, js, html, xml etc, os item marcados em vermelhos podem ser da demora da validação. Tente deixar uns 3 projetos abertos so e veja se o 'erro' persiste.

Comment: No caso, este erro -> http://prntscr.com/71m51a <- Se eu tirar o ponto e vírgula, salvar e depois colocar novamente, simplesmente some o erro

Comment: Na aba "Problems" aparece alguma mensagem explicando melhor do que se trata o erro? Qual?

Comment: Math, na aba de problemas isto nem aparece... Mas por exemplo: Quando eu passo o mouse em cima do erro apenas aparece "Syntax error on token "}", { expected". Todos erros quase são assim... meu amigo já teve este problema também, ele teve que reinstalar o eclipse.